# Why does the install of a mobileconfig need a wifi reboot to take effect ?

Tags: ios, http, proxy, wifi

I am trying to programmatically configure a [HTTP Proxy configuration profile](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW34) on my iOS7+ devices. So far, I was able to  :

- create a .mobileconfig
- send the user to the Settings.app
- make the user install the configuration profile
- send the user back to my app

My problem is that, at this point, the proxy configuration does not seem to be taken into account yet. I noticed that I needed to switch the wifi off and on to make it work.

Do you know if there is a way to make the proxy configuration work without switching the Wifi off and on ?